# Get single record from db in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

**views.py**

```
from .models import Customer as CustomerModel

class Balance_Enquiry(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'balance_enuiry.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if "user_id" in request.session:
            try:
                customer = CustomerModel.objects.get(user_id=request.session["user_id"])
                args = {'form': form, 'posts': customer}
                return render(request, self.template_name, args)
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse('failed: {}'.format(e), 500)
```

**template**

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Balance Enquiry{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="get" >
    {% csrf_token %}

        <table border="5">
            <tr>
            <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
            </tr>
     {% for get in customer %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ get.amount }}</td>
                <td>{{ get.contact }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

i just want to get single person record after login it show the record of that person but it not show anything on screen it show just blank and even not got any error

Comment: Here `args = {'form': form, 'posts': customer}` you put customer to context and then in template you're iterating through `customer`. Where does this defined? Why you are calling customer as `posts`?

Comment: i got error 'Customer' object is not iterable

Comment: From your code it's not obvious what is `customer`. Can you show the definition of this variable you put in context? Also, why are you iterating via single record?

Comment: in customer i store the object of Customer table

Comment: i just want to get single record of person which login mean his contact_no amount etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get single data with `get()` method you can not for loop, because you take non iterable object. Remove for loop in your template. Also you must use same keyword for context and template variables.

views:

```
args = {'form': form, 'customer': customer}
```

templates:

```
    <tr>
        <td>{{ customer.amount }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.contact }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: thnak u so much for help

Comment: one more thing if i want to get User table attribute also with same user_id so how can  i do

Comment: I didn't understand your problem clearly, iyf you give more detail I want to help you

Comment: i mean i want access auth_user table and get the information of particular person i.e email, first_name etc then i also get value from other table where account information is store in other table which is amount and contact no

Comment: `user = User.objects.get(pk=request.session["user_id"])` you can get user object and after that, you can access your user fields like that: `user.email`, `user.first_name`. You can use this steps for other tables. If it doesn't please ask me again

Comment: can i ask one last thing?

Comment: i make login form where i take username and passsword if user is authenticated then he/she will go customer menu there he/she can perform opretion deposit , withdraw and balance enquiry. i make it for customer but i want when an employee login he/she perform their opreation like customers_info and also close account but i don't know can i define which one is customer and which one i s employee

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=18a0mQxZAiLT9AhTeNVd3xE7GSJjs93H1

Comment: You must define role or you can store this information in your model, after user login, you can redirect depends on his group or role. There is very good example [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208577/discussion-between-muhammad-usman-and-kamilyrb).

Comment: can u help me i can't send the confirmation mail through django